# PHP login validation on the same page?

Tags: php, html

Could anyone explain me how to check and register username and password in the same page?

How can I echo the "wrong username and password" message in the form?

Thanks in advance.

**Check Login**

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
  session_register("myusername");
  session_register("mypassword");
  header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
  echo "Wrong Username or Password";
```

**FORM**

```
<form class="clearfix" name="form1" method="POST" action="">
```

Comment: You can start by looking tutorials 

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Comment: You should use Ajax method to send the data to server.

Comment: @fluminis could you find a tutorial that uses pdo? :)

Comment: why you tag this for Zend framework and cakephp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the form action to the current .php file. In the script, check whether you already submitted the form (e.g. the submit button has a value in `$_POST`)

If there is an answer, proceed with the login code. If no, create a new variable, like `$errorMessage`. Echo this error message somewhere in the form. (If this is time first time the user loads the script, there will be nothing in this variable, thus it will display nothing.)

It'd be more elegant if you put the echo of $errorMessage in an if statement with some `<div>`s or whatever you'd like to use for this task.

Answer (score 0):

really basics

```
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
     // user have submitted the form , proceed checking username/password and then start session
    }else{
     // display login form
    }
```

Comment: true added isset() to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

To display the error make a variable `$error = "Wrong Username or Password";`

Then at the bottom of your form just write :

```
if(isset($error)) {
    echo $error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset` and `isempty` to check the data returned.

```
if(isset($_POST["formvariable"]))
{ }
```

also in the form field change action to `"currentfilename.php"`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the Ajax method. The end result is much cleaner.